# How to trigger notification on controller return?

Tags: laravel, notifications

I'm on laravel 8, and on my project I want to trigger some sort of notification for example if the user succesfully update their account then on return it will give some notification that update is success, I want it to be modal or alert. I've tried the withMsg or with inside my controller but none of them works, I tested the function with button trigger action and it works, but I want it to activated automatically. 
also forgot to mention that when I was still on stock laravel template the message function works, until I change to other template it won't work again

does anyone have a solution? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're referring to a `flash` message where information is stored in the session and displayed on the next request (or longer if you wish). The Laravel documentation explains [how to set a flash message in the session](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data).

There are some excellent resources available on how to compose flash messages, whether as an alert or as a modal. Laracasts has such a tutorial on [flash messaging and modals](https://laracasts.com/series/hands-on-community-contributions/episodes/7).

[SweetAlert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) is a popular package for creating modal notifications and there is a 'sweet` (pun intended) [package for Laravel](https://realrashid.github.io/sweet-alert/) that wraps the original package into a nice API for you to use in your Laravel projects.

Comment: aah I see, I ended up using the SweetAlert which is a very nice and easy library to use! thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice library for alerts that are easy to call, you just call things like `alert()->success('It worked!)` in your controller and it'll pop up once the page loads (assuming you set it up correctly), its a Laravel wrapper around sweatalert https://github.com/realrashid/sweet-alert

Comment: thanks!, that's a very nice library wnd very easy to use!